# ImageResizer.net isn't saving as .jpg when format set

Tags: image-resizing, imageresizer

I am using the ImageResizer.net library (http://imageresizing.net/) to manipulate images. I want to save all images as .jpg. I have the following code:

```
ImageJob i = new ImageResizer.ImageJob(srcPath, destPath, new
    ImageResizer.ResizeSettings("width=220;height=306;format=jpg;quality=80;mode=stretch"));
i.Build();
```

According to the documentation, format=jpg should save the image as a .jpg. However, the image is being saved as its original type.

Any ideas on how I can save all images as .jpg? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It *IS* saving your image as a jpeg.

It is *not* changing the extension, because you're not permitting it to.

Either pass "true" for the `addFileExtension` parameter:

```
ImageJob i = new ImageResizer.ImageJob(srcPath, destPath, new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings  
    ("width=220;height=306;format=jpg;quality=80;mode=stretch"), true);
i.Build();
```

Or use filename variables:

```
ImageJob i = new ImageResizer.ImageJob(srcPath, destPath + ".<ext>", new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings  
    ("width=220;height=306;format=jpg;quality=80;mode=stretch"));
i.Build();
```